# Dependencies between github projects that compile via maven

Tags: java, git, maven, github

Looking for the best option, or a solution I am unaware of:

> **(probably unnecessary context)** I developed "project A", a 1990's RPG video game ported to Java. Currently starting on "project B", a server to co-ordinate project A to run as a MMORPG.

Project A, lives in gitHub, compiles in maven and has no dependencies on project B.
Project B, (will) live in gitHub, has dependencies on "project A", and aspires to compile in maven

- I would like both to sit in separate github repositories
- I would like project B's pom.xml to specify the version of 'project A' needed.

  - No preference if this is achieved via specifying a git branch/version or maven artifactId/version.
- I would like running maven for project B to find either:

  - (if available) Project A's last local build of specified version.
  - (fallback) Projects A's latest version on gitHub
- I would prefer not to host project A Jars in some url (or git repo from project A, or B), as they will become large due to graphics. Also that type of thing rubs me the wrong way.
- I would like "project B" to "just work" via a 'git clone ...', followed by a 'mvn package'.

There seems to be a multitude of approaches:

- via 3rd party: eg jitpack
- via maven reactor / modules (with what appear to be several sub approaches)
- running 'mvn install' from project A
- nexus, artifactory
- via git submodules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like both to sit in separate github repositories

that's trivial

> I would like project B's pom.xml to specify the version of 'project A' needed.

you can use version to distinguish your jars

> I would like running maven for project B to find either:
>   (if available) Project A's last local build of specified version.
>   (fallback) Projects A's latest version on gitHub

that's maven by design

> I would prefer not to host project A Jars in some url (or git repo from project A, or B), as they will become large due to graphics. Also that type of thing rubs me the wrong way.

have you consider to separate resources from core? ie put them in separate project given that they least likely to change

now solution, in my opionion what you need is remote maven repository (by remote i mean opposite to local which will be accessable whenever you want to work on your project. personally i would recommend nexus, but i might be biased here, given that i have most experience with it.
other solution might be maven repository on github. never tried it, but it looks [ok](https://gist.github.com/fernandezpablo85/03cf8b0cd2e7d8527063)

Comment: Cheers for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- check out both projects on your computer, build project A with version x.y.z and then build B against A with that version. This works through the local Maven repository on your computer.
- put both B and A into a multi-module project so that you can build everything at once. This means that both projects have to be in subdirectories of some parent directory.
- Use your own Nexus/Artifactory. Then you can `mvn deploy` B in a version to this repository and resolve it in A through the same one. Works more or less like the local repository, but is much more convenient to use and search in.